# Regex count for replace string in Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2

Is there a regex escape code for counting matched groups?

Such as replacing:

```
foo
foo
foo
```

With:

```
foo x 3
```

**Search:** ((foo)\n)+

**Replace:** $2 x **??**\n

Comment: What do you mean by `$2 x ??\n`?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im OP is looking to replace __n__ instances of some token with `{token} x n`

Comment: Right, looking for equivalent of:
`string.Format("{0} x {1}\n", match.Groups[2].Value, match.Groups[1].Captures.Count)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this based on regex alone. Here's an example in Javascript:

```
var myText = "foo\nfoo\nfoo";
var line = myText.match(/(.+)(?=\r?\n\1$)/mg)[0];
var re = new RegExp(line + "\r?\n(?=" + line + "$)","mg");
myText = line + " x " + (myText.match(re).length + 1);
```

Result:

```
foo x 3
```

If you want to do it over multiple values, like "foo\nfoo\nfoo\nbar\nbar" then I suggest you split the string into an array first.

Comment: Yeah, this is how I would do it with C#: http://ideone.com/57JvkF but, I was trying to just clean up a log file in my text editor (Sublime Text 2). Thanks in any case, maybe this will help someone else if they are using Java

Comment: There may not be a solution...  I knew that regex keeps track of captures, and there is syntax for matching based on count using {COUNT}, such as ((foo)\n){3} to match exactly 3 instances of that group. So I was curious if there was a way that I wasn't aware of to get that count in a replace expression, without additional logic or lambda expressions.

Comment: Not as far as I'm concerned, sorry.